# Campo com valor diferente do esperado com Laravel e php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho um campo no banco de ate 50 caracteres onde salvo a chave de acesso de uma nota fiscal, mas quando eu busco a informação ele me traz um numero totalmente diferente, o que acontece?

```
Schema::create('nfe_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('nfe_chave', 50);
        $table->integer('nfe_numero');
        $table->string('nfe_serie', 10);
        $table->string('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_emit', 18);
        $table->foreign('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_emit')->references('parc_cpf_cnpj')->on('parceiros_table');
        $table->string('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_dest', 18);
        $table->foreign('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_dest')->references('parc_cpf_cnpj')->on('parceiros_table');
        $table->string('nfe_desc_nat_op', 200);
        $table->dateTime('nfe_dt_emiss');
        $table->dateTime('nfe_dt_receb');
        $table->dateTime('nfe_dt_venc')->nullable();
        $table->double('nfe_vl');
        $table->string('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_transp', 18)->default("");
        $table->foreign('nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_transp')->references('parc_cpf_cnpj')->on('parceiros_table');
        $table->string('nfe_tp_frete', 3)->default(0);
        $table->string('nfe_transp_placa', 9)->default("");
        $table->string('nfe_transp_placa_uf', 3)->default("");
        $table->integer('nfe_vol')->default(0);
        $table->string('nfe_vol_especie')->default("VOL");
        $table->double('nfe_peso_bruto')->default(0);
        $table->double('nfe_peso_liq')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('nfe_is_recebida')->default(0);
        $table->integer('nfe_user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('nfe_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('nfe_inf_adic', 1000)->default("");
        $table->primary(['nfe_chave']);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Model NFE

```
use Notifiable;
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

protected $table = 'nfe_table';
protected $primaryKey = 'nfe_chave';

protected $fillable = [
    'nfe_chave', 'nfe_numero', 'nfe_serie',
    'nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_emit', 'nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_dest', 'nfe_desc_nat_op', 'nfe_dt_emiss', 'nfe_dt_receb', 'nfe_dt_venc', 'nfe_vl',
    'nfe_parc_cpf_cnpj_transp', 'nfe_tp_frete', 'nfe_transp_placa', 'nfe_transp_placa_uf', 'nfe_vol', 'nfe_vol_especie',
    'nfe_peso_bruto', 'nfe_peso_liq', 'nfe_is_recebida', 'nfe_user_id', 'nfe_inf_adic', 'nfe_confirm_receb',
];
```

acessando a variável objeto da nota no método dd:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas acessando ela diretamente com por exemplo:

```
dd($nfe->nfe_chave);
```

Me traz isso, não entendo e eu precisava mostrar a chave em um formulário de recebimento

9223372036854775807

Comment: Por acaso no seu model existe alguma função com o mesmo nome desse atributo?
Pergunto porque aconteceu exatamente isso comigo, quando eu tentava pegar um valor de um atributo, me retornava um valor diferente do salvo, mas era pq eu tinha uma função de relacionamento no meu model, com isso ele executava a função q retornava outro valor e não o valor real do atributo.

Comment: É uma funcionalidade nova ainda não criei métodos para trazer dentro do model! e continua me trazendo um valor que não está salvo, muito estranho! engraçado que é o único campo me trazendo valor incorreto e no método dd(); ele me traz o valor correto mas na hora de utilizar e me traz um valor diferente!

Comment: Faz o mesmo teste com outra nota fiscal.

Comment: Todas com o mesmo problema e eu preciso da chave de acesso pra poder utilizar ela para consultar as notas! só que eu não entendo é que para todas a notas ele me mostra o mesmo valor ( 9223372036854775807 ), de onde ele pega esse número?

Comment: Pior é que já pesquisei muito e não encontro nada pra tentar solucionar isso!

Comment: Coloca sua função toda onde acontece isso. Remove esse código da migration deixa só o código onde o problema acontece.

Comment: Criei uma solução de contorno mas se alguém puder me dar uma luz, a chave de acesso é minha chave primaria, criei um campo como cópia da chave, e como ele não é a primaria me trouxe o valor correto! não sei porque isso acontece!

Comment: Como não consigo ainda comentar, faz o favor, manda o código do Model NFE e o código de listagem disso por favor.

Comment: Vou tentar colocar na pergunta!